# Sending Email using stimulsoft VB code

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, stimulsoft

Could anyone tell me how to send email using stimulsoft reports in mvc?

When I read the manual I found this code:

```
//razor:
========
@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(
"MvcViewer1", new StiMvcViewerOptions() {
Actions =
{
EmailReport = "EmailReport"
},
Toolbar =
{
ShowSendEmailButton = true
}
})


    //controller:
    //===========

    public ActionResult EmailReport()
    {
      StiEmailOptions options = StiMvcViewer.GetEmailOptions();

      // Passed from the viewer, can be checked and adjusted
      // options.AddressTo = "";
      // options.Subject = "";
      // options.Body = "";

      // Should be filled here
      options.AddressFrom = "admin_address@gmail.com";
      options.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
      options.Port = 465;
      options.UserName = "admin_address@gmail.com";
      options.Password = "admin_password";

    return StiMvcViewer.EmailReportResult(options);
    }
```

I tried to map this code to visual basic but i couldn't find `EmailReportResult()` method and I got error:

> 'EmailReportResult' is not a member of 'Stimulsoft.Report.Mvc.StiMvcViewer'.

Comment: It should be a member. What steps did the manual show? You added your references, any necessary components, imported?

Comment: yes i added all required references, also the razor code is :
========
@Html.Stimulsoft().StiMvcViewer(
"MvcViewer1", new StiMvcViewerOptions() {
Actions =
{
EmailReport = "EmailReport"
},
Toolbar =
{
ShowSendEmailButton = true
}
})

could you help me to convert it to vb ?